# jquery selector for differentiating between single and dynamic id input type?

Tags: jquery

How is it possible to differentiate between following type of id using jQuery?

1. `id="sectionId_1"`
2. `id="sectionId_1_1"`

I have tried the following:

```
$(".row").find("input[id^='sectionId_']").each(function(){
```

========

## Edit:

```
    There are two types of pattern
    1. id="sectionId_'+i+'" (section) where i can be 0,1,2 etc
    2. id="sectionId_'+i+'_'+j+'" (subsection) where i and j can be 0,1,2 
    etc
    for the second case i & j relationship is somewhat like nested for loop

    I need to get the values of section and subsection separately in 
    different .each loop and put it in separate array as well
```

Comment: what do you mean by `type of id`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: your question seems to be unclear

Answer (score -1):

I have made a fiddle for the query.

https://jsfiddle.net/op5uv6mg/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$("div").find("input[id^='sectionId_']").css("border", "1px solid green");


$("div").find("input[id^='sectionId_1_']").css("border", "1px solid pink");


});
```